# jQuery UI AutoComplete Combobox Options require double click on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova, combobox

I have created an app with Cordova that contains jQuery custom autocomplete comboboxes. It works perfectly on the browser as well as on the physical **android** device. However now that I put the app on the **iPhone** I encounter a small bug which is could be very annoying for the end users.

**The Bug:**
Once the options are displayed from the combobox to the user, they must click once, which hi-lights their choice, and then a **second** click to actually make the selection. The intended use as it is on the Android devices is to only click once on the option to make the selection.

**Before any Clicks**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEKbT.png

**First Click**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEAfo.png

The first click should be making the selection but instead just hi-lights the option and waits for the user to click on the highlighted option once again. Also the same issue happens on the iPhone simulator as well as on the physical device, so I don't believe it is device specific.

Here is the **HTML**

```
<div class="ui-widget"><select id="testCombo"></select></div>
```

**Js** to turn it into a ComboBox

```
$("#testCombo").combobox()
```

And here is the custom widget being used for the **Combo Box**

```
(function( $ ) {
$.widget( "custom.combobox", {
    options: {
        'userChanged': function() {
    //@Overridden if needed
        }
},

_create: function() {
    this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
    .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
    .insertAfter( this.element );

        this.element.hide();
        this._createAutocomplete();
        this._createShowAllButton();
},

_createAutocomplete: function() {
        var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
    value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

        this.input = $( "<input>" )
    .appendTo( this.wrapper )
    .val( value )
    .attr( "title", "" )
    .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
    .autocomplete({
        delay: 0,
        minLength: 0,
        source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
    })
    .tooltip({
        tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
    });

        this._on( this.input, {
    autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.item.option.selected = true;
        this._trigger( "select", event, {
        item: ui.item.option
        });
    },

    //* Remove commented code below so that if User types
    //a value not in options, it gets removed 
    //autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
    autocompletechange: "userChanged"
        });
},

_createShowAllButton: function() {
        var input = this.input,
    wasOpen = false;

        $( "<a>" )
    .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
    //      .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
    .tooltip()
    .appendTo( this.wrapper )
    .button({
        icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
        },
        text: false
    })
    .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
    .addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
    .mousedown(function() {
        wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
    })
    .click(function() {
        input.focus();

        // Close if already visible
        if ( wasOpen ) {
        return;
        }

        // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
        input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
    });
},

_source: function( request, response ) {
        var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
        response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
    var text = $( this ).text();
    if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
        return {
        label: text,
        value: text,
        option: this
        };
        }) );
},

_removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {

        // Selected an item, nothing to do
        if ( ui.item ) {
    return;
        }

        // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
        var value = this.input.val(),
    valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
    valid = false;
        this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
    if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
        this.selected = valid = true;
        return false;
    }
        });

        // Found a match, nothing to do
        if ( valid ) {
    return;
        }

        // Remove invalid value
        this.input
    .val( "" )
    .attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
    .tooltip( "open" );
        this.element.val( "" );
        this._delay(function() {
    this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
        }, 2500 );
        this.input.autocomplete( "instance" ).term = "";
},

_destroy: function() {
        this.wrapper.remove();
        this.element.show();
},

//set value for combobox
autocomplete : function(value) {
    this.element.val(value);
    this.input.val(value);      
},

//set the placeholder of the combobox
placeholder : function(value) {
    this.element.attr("placeholder",value);
    this.input.attr("placeholder",value);
},

//used to get the custom typed text from the autoCombo
getval: function(){
    var value = this.input.val();
    if (value === ""){
    return null;
    }else{
    return value;
    }
},

userChanged: function() {
    if($.isFunction(this.options.userChanged))
            this.options.userChanged();
    }

});
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be related to tooltip. Iphone is firstly executing hover events then next click is real click event. I had same problem and removed "hover" items solved my problem.

Comment: I removed all hover styles and that didn't seem to fix the issue